# Uploading Files wont work codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I am banging my head in the wall for about 3 hours. I tried to search also over in the internet why the file to be uploaded wont upload in the folder, can you help me?

file upload permission set to 0777

here's my view

```
  <?php echo form_open_multipart('home_members/do_upload', array('class' => 'form-horizontal','id' => 'MyForm')); ?>

     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="scan">Upload File:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input class="input-xlarge" name="userfile[]" id="userfile" type="file" multiple="" />
        </div>
    </div>     

    <div class="form-actions">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sell Card" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>                         
    <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

controllers:

```
public function do_upload() 
{
    $name_array = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);

    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {

            $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];  

            $config['upload_path'] = base_url() . 'uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
        }
        $names= implode(',', $name_array);
        /* $this->load->database();
        $db_data = array('id'=> NULL,
        'name'=> $names);
        $this->db->insert('testtable',$db_data);
        */  print_r($names);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing just one file? Instead of multiple files? Also, use the display_errors function to help you. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: yes but it doesn't upload in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you use codeigniter upload library you cannot set input file names as array as you used `userfile[]` you should name it `userfile`, If you want multiple file upload you should name it `userfile1`,`userfile2`... Remember It should not be array.

**Note** I am not 100% sure about array input names.
You can solve your problem like this

```
<input class="input-xlarge" name="userfile1" id="userfile1" type="file"/>
<input class="input-xlarge" name="userfile2" id="userfile2" type="file"/>
```

Now your upload function should be like this

```
public function do_upload() 
{

    $CI = & get_instance();
    //if you are inside controller you can use $this
    $CI->load->library('upload');
    $config=array();
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;

    $name_array = array();
    foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
    {

            $CI->upload->initialize($config);
            if ($CI->upload->do_upload($key))
            {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];//I normally use $name_array[] = $data.Then check it with my expected input fields
            }

    }
    print_r($name_array);
}
```

Hope it may help you.

Comment: opps it should be `$name_array`

Comment: Hi I got  `Array ( )` error.  by the way, what is the file loading in CI->load->library('upload');? and where this file located?

Comment: it means no file is uploading.Make sure you have uploads folder.You can `echo $CI->upload->display_errors()` on else condition to display what error you getting

Comment: Hi, How to check if file upload is no error? I want to have if else.

Comment: I'm getting `You did not select a file to upload` even I have selected file.

Comment: Now I have tested my code and its working fine. Can You please update your question what you have done.(your view and controller)

Comment: Im getting an error `You did not select a file to upload` even I selected a file in my form.

Comment: I am 100% sure you did not changed your file input name `userfile[]`. change it to `userfile`

Comment: `<input class="input-xlarge" name="userfile1" id="userfile" type="file" /><input class="input-xlarge" name="userfile2" id="userfile" type="file" />` I try to upload two files but when I submit the form it shows `You did not select a file to upload` why was that?